# Ornamental border on a frame or page

Tags: image-editing, libreoffice-draw

LibreOffice Draw is a useful application for laying out a page. How can I apply an ornamental border, made of images (e.g. abstract curves or floral effects)?

The idea is to define an image for each corner and have the border continuous between corners, even when the frame or page is resized.

In LibreOffice generally, I don't see options except to have straight-line geometric borders; in LibreOffice Draw, I don't see easy options to add explicit borders to anything.

How do we easily add ornamental borders to an area on a page?